# How do I make sure Siri always suggests calling phone numbers listed as calendar locations?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, siri

Siri Suggestions is an awesome feature, but lately it has been inconsistent. When working properly, Siri would provide a shortcut on my iPhone's lock screen to call the phone number of my next phone meeting when it was nearly time to start the meeting. I believe it was able to pull from Apple Calendar, Fantastical 2, and Outlook. But lately it has not been as reliable.

Is there special syntax required? For instance, does the location field have to contain a phone number *and only a phone number?* Sometimes I provide locations like "Webex & ###-###-####" when there's a screen share or video component to the meeting.